# Inconsistency of control_dependencies in distributed TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I wrote a simple test code to test `tf.control_dependencies()` between two machines. I think the code always have to return the same result, but the result is not consistent.

#### Code

There are two hosts and each has its own variable. One of them update its variable via SGD, and when it ends, another host copies the resulted variable to its own variable.

```py
### test.py ###
import tensorflow as tf

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('task_id', 0, 'Unique task ID. One of 0 or 1.')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({'hosts': ['10.0.0.1:7001', '10.0.0.2:7001']})
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, task_index=FLAGS.task_id, protocol='grpc')

# Host 1 is passive
if FLAGS.task_id == 1:
    server.join()

# Host 0 builds the operation graph

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
with tf.device('/task:1/device:CPU:0'):
    # Task 1 optimizes its own variable
    var1 = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
    apply_op = opt.minimize(tf.square(var1 - 2.))

with tf.device('/task:0/device:CPU:0'):
    # Task 0 copies the optimized result to its own variable
    var0 = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
    with tf.control_dependencies([apply_op]):
        new_var0 = tf.assign(var0, var1)

sess = tf.Session(target=server.target)
# initialize variables
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
# expected: [0.4, 0.4]
print(sess.run([new_var0, var1]))
```

I execute this code via typing `python test.py --task_id=0` on host 0 (10.0.0.1) and `python test.py --task_id=1` on host 1 (10.0.0.2).

I expect `[0.4, 0.4]` to be printed, because `var1` is updated via `apply_op`, and the resulted `var1` is copied to `var0`, so that both `var0` and `var1` have updated values. However, the result is one of `[0.0, 0.4]` or `[0.4, 0.0]` or `[0.4, 0.4]`, and it changes every time I execute the code. Why does this happen?

#### Important Features

If I use `'/task:0/device:CPU:0'` for both variables, the result is always `[0.4, 0.4]` as I expected, which may indicate that the problem is from communication between machines.

Also, if I use `'/task:1/device:CPU:0'` for both variables, the result is one of `[0.4, 0]` or `[0.4, 0.4]`.

#### System Information (for both machines)

Linux Ubuntu 16.04.1, CUDA 8.0,

TensorFlow r1.1, GPU version, installed from source

(commit 1ec6ed51182adf8f1b03a3188c16cd8a45ca6c85)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue is that `tf.Variable` takes cached snapshots of variables. This is an optimization that minimizes transfers in distributed training, but can have some surprising implications.

Try using `tf.Variable.read_value()` to grab the latest copy.

See the documentation for `value()` and `read_value()`:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#value
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#read_value

Hope that helps!

Comment: Using `read_value()` helped to copy the updated value. Thank you very much!